# How to set the lifetime on these structures?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to make an Iterator which filters out certain moves from a movelist. In order not to take ownership of the returned moves, they get referenced. However, when doing that, the `missing lifetime specifier` compiler error appears. As I have a chain of structs, I thought the first step to solve the problem was to start putting lifetimes on `MoveFilter` and then onto it's `type Item` in `IntoIterator`. However there it complains the usage of an undeclared lifetime. 
Code:

```
pub struct GameMove {
    pub from: usize,
    pub to: usize,
    pub move_type: GameMoveType,
    pub piece_type: PieceType,
}
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum GameMoveType {
    Quiet,
    Capture(PieceType),
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum PieceType {
    King,
    Pawn
}

pub fn match_move_type(move_type: &GameMoveType) -> usize {
    match move_type {
        GameMoveType::Quiet => 0,
        GameMoveType::Capture(_) => 1,
    }
}

pub struct MoveFilter<'a> {
    legal_moves: Vec<GameMove>,
    move_type: GameMoveType,
}

impl IntoIterator for MoveFilter {
    type Item = &'a GameMove;
    type IntoIter = MoveFilterIterator;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        MoveFilterIterator {
            legal_moves: self.legal_moves,
            move_type: match_move_type(&self.move_type),
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

pub struct MoveFilterIterator {
    legal_moves: Vec<GameMove>,
    move_type: usize,
    index: usize,
}

impl Iterator for MoveFilterIterator {
    type Item = &GameMove;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&GameMove> {
        while self.index < self.legal_moves.len() {
            if match_move_type(&self.legal_moves[self.index].move_type) == self.move_type {
                Some(&self.legal_moves[self.index])
            } else {
                self.index += 1;
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that an alternative solution to using references to `GameMoveType` would be just to derive `Copy` for it (which would in turn require the same for`PieceType`). The types seem pretty lightweight, so `Copy` seems appropriate - unless you've stripped out some expensive-to-copy components from the definitions for the MCVE, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discrepancy between your
method `fn into_iter(self: MoveFilter)` that takes ownership of `MoveFilter`
and
the method `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&GameMove>` that only wants to hand out immutable references to `GameMove`s. Who is supposed to own the referenced `GameMove`s after your `into_iter` takes ownership of the `MoveFilter` and completely consumes it?

One way to fix it would be to implement `IntoIterator` for `&'a MoveFilter`, that does not take ownership of `MoveFilter`, and thus does not have to worry that all `GameMove`s are discarded while there are any references `&'a GameMove` floating around:

```
pub struct GameMove {
    pub from: usize,
    pub to: usize,
    pub move_type: GameMoveType,
    pub piece_type: PieceType,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum GameMoveType {
    Quiet,
    Capture(PieceType),
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum PieceType {
    King,
    Pawn
}

pub fn match_move_type(move_type: &GameMoveType) -> usize {
    match move_type {
        GameMoveType::Quiet => 0,
        GameMoveType::Capture(_) => 1,
    }
}

pub struct MoveFilter {
    legal_moves: Vec<GameMove>,
    move_type: GameMoveType,
}

impl<'t> IntoIterator for &'t MoveFilter {
    type Item = &'t GameMove;
    type IntoIter = MoveFilterIterator<'t>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        MoveFilterIterator {
            legal_moves: &self.legal_moves[..],
            move_type: match_move_type(&self.move_type),
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

pub struct MoveFilterIterator<'a> {
    legal_moves: &'a [GameMove],
    move_type: usize,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MoveFilterIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a GameMove;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a GameMove> {
        while self.index < self.legal_moves.len() {
            if match_move_type(&self.legal_moves[self.index].move_type) == self.move_type {
                return Some(&self.legal_moves[self.index])
            } else {
                self.index += 1;
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

Another possible solution would be to leave your `IntoIterator for MoveFilter` as-is, but then change `Item = &GameMove` to `Item = GameMove`. This would give you a destructive iterator that moves the `MoveFilter` and that can be used only once, but I assume that's not what you wanted when you began with `type Item = &GameMove`. Implementing it seems a bit more awkward, because it's not entirely trivial to remove single elements from a vector, and I didn't quite understand what that `while`-loop was doing there.

Comment: The while loop is there to go to the next move if it the one at the current index doesn't match the specified move-type.

Comment: @Fabianv.d.W I guess I'll have to just believe you here, because I don't know how you decided to model the domain, and I don't even understand the domain very well... Another remark: the `IntoIterator for &'a FooBar` is quite a common idiom, check out some of the examples [in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#implementors), roughly half(?) of them look like `IntoIterator for &'a Something`.

Comment: Isn't the implemented iterator destructive anyway, since it takes ownership of the Vec<GameMove>? So in anyway, I can use it only once or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Fabianv.d.W That's the reason why I replaced the owning `Vec<GameMove>` by the immutable reference `&'a [GameMove]`.

Comment: I see, but doesn't the into_iter function of MoveFilter take ownership of MoveFilter which in turn takes ownership of legal_moves?

Comment: @Fabianv.d.W No, it doesn't. The method `fn into_iter(self)` takes a `self: Self`, and `Self` has now been changed to `Self = &'t MoveFilter` instead of `Self = MoveFilter`. Don't confuse it with `into_iter()` on owning vectors or something like that: for an owning vector, it produces a destructive iterator. But here, I implemented it for an immutable reference `&'t MoveFilter`, so `into_iter()` doesn't move anything.

Comment: Right, thanks, that resolved the issues in my head. For now, I have also changed your &'a [GameMove] into &'a Vec<GameMove> that also seems to work. BTW: I can't seem to tag you on those comments, and how do you use the markdown for code in comments?

Comment: @Fabianv.d.W Tagging (if you mean the (at)-thing) is not necessary, because I'm notified about all comments under my postings anyway (that's how it works in general). Inline code in comments works the same way as in postings: enclose the code in backticks (I think the backticks must "touch" the non-whitespace portion of the code).

Comment: Another question I had was that my enum GameMoveType has the field Capture(PieceType) Now if i wanted to compare two GameMoveTypes if they are both captures regardless of what inner PieceType they have, how would I do that? I solved it with the function match_move_type you can see above, which maps a GameMoveType to a number, but I feel like there must a better way to do that.